# How to run the parameter xml from a testng class

Tags: xml, selenium, jar, testng, executable

I currently have a TestNG framework in Eclipse with two TestNG classes in which parameters to one of the TestNG class is passed from an XML. I usually run this XML as TestNG for running the testcase. Now I am trying to create an executable jar out of this which I am not able to.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast I got it worked. I invoked the parameter testng.xml from a Java class and ran it using Java application. After creating the Java class, I exported the Project as runnable JAR file. Now I can run my tests from JAR file outside eclipse also.

Below is the Java class I created

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
@Test
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> file = new ArrayList<String>();
    file.add("D:/Selenium_workspace/Framework/src/Framework.xml");
    TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
    testNG.setTestSuites(file);
    testNG.run();}
}
```

Thankyou all.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create one class which is equivalent to testng.xml. That class should have main method and all the operation that you are performing in testng.xml you will have to mimick it in that class. This is called as running testng programmatically by using org.testng.TestNG class. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically . After this create an executable jar using eclipse where you will have to specify this class as the class containing main method. Let me know if you need further help on this.

Comment: Thank you  I created a class which having main method equivalent to the XML used for passing parameter.
But when I run the main class(having main method) using TestNG, I get the below message.
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method main requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation.

My XML file name is eg: Framework.xml
Inside which Suite name=Suite.
Below is the format of parameter XML file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
  <test name="Test">
    <parameter name="excel_path" value="Input Path" />.....

Comment: If this helped you then please accept this as answer.

Comment: Yes, but I am getting error while running the class. Method main requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation

Comment: Can you post your TestNG class. probably u r not supplying the parameter to the test method which you were supplying from testng.xml

Comment: @Parameters({"excel_path","output_path"})
public class MainOne{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
  suite.setName("Suite");
   XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
  test.setName("Suite");
  List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
  classes.add(new XmlClass("Suite"));
  test.setXmlClasses(classes);
  List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
  suites.add(suite);
  TestNG tng = new TestNG();
  tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
  tng.run();
  } 
}

Comment: And My XMl suite is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
  <test name="Test">
   <parameter name="excel_path" value="D:\Selenium_workspace\My_framework.xlsx" />
   <parameter name="tobeexecuted_index" value="3" />
   <parameter name="data_index" value="9" />
   <parameter name="excelsheet_name" value="Framework_Sheet" />
    <classes>
      <class name="test_Suite.test_Framework"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->